# Find closed issues in App Quality Insights

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics

Currently, I am using *Android Studio Giraffe* version. After **close** an issue from *App Quality Insights*, I am unable to locate the issue again even after refreshing. Specifically, I cannot view closed issues within the feature. Is there an option available to view closed issues?